# setTimeout within .each doenst work

Tags: jquery

It might seems like im doing things a strange way but im tying to build my code in stage so I can understand whats going on. The following fades out elements after a delay.

```
        $('.image-list .bottom').each(function(i){
                $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
        });
```

I wanted to add a delay of 1 second before this happens but with the code below nothing happens at all.

```
        $('.image-list .bottom').each(function(i){  
            setTimeout(function(){  
                $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
            },1000);    
        });
```

I know that I could change the delay in the annimation, and that the each function isnt necessary at this stage, but im tying to build something more complex and get my head around the basics of this structure.

Comment: It has $(this) same issue :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're actually running the stTimeout at the same time (.each is very fast here), so you should schedule manually, Try this: (1000 --> 1000*i),

Also you need to cache the object outisde the setTimeout function

```
$('.image-list .bottom').each(function(i){  
            var $item = $(this);
            setTimeout(function(){  
                $item.delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
            },1000*i);    
        });
```

Comment: If im running the setTimeout at the same time, shouldn't they all delay and then fade out at the same time? This is what I expected but actually nothing happens.

Comment: Ah I see $item is needed for this.

Comment: OK, so if you want them all to happen at the same time remove the *i I suggested ;)

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the callback method does not point to the `bottom` element it was looping.

One solution is to use a closure variable

```
    $('.image-list .bottom').each(function(i){  
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){  
            $(self ).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
        },1000);    
    });
```

Another is to use `$.proxy()` to pass a custom execution context

```
    $('.image-list .bottom').each(function(i){  
        setTimeout($.proxy(function(){  
            $(self ).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
        }, this),1000);    
    });
```